# Prevent sql injection by removing characters and other possible ways

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-injection

SQL injection can be avoided if I remove "`'`" character in the variables of a sql query. The sql query that I use is:

```
dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("update Table1 set PhoneNo = '" + phone + "' where Table1.Company = '" + company + "'", dbConnection);
dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I also use SELECT sql query in a similar way:

```
dbReader = new OleDbCommand("select * from Table1 where Table1.Company = '" + company + "'", dbConnection).ExecuteReader();
dbReader.Read();

if (dbReader.HasRows)
{
    //Do operations using dbReader["Company"]
}
```

Are there any other characters in the variables that can cause SQL injection or other risks? I can remove those. What are other ways of preventing SQL injection or other risks?

Comment: Don't do it that way - just use parameterized queries!

Comment: The best way? Do not compose the SQL query string using user provided strings, use @ parameters and you'll be safe from any sql injection.

Comment: Ok. thanks for the valuable comments. I will use parametrized queries. I get variables from users in textbox. I can also avoid the characters in the input itself. Is there a list of all possible risky characters?

Comment: If you use parameterized queries then you don't have to care about any character, they're all safe. This doesn't mean you do not have to VALIDATE your inputs, just you don't need to "sanitize" them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is simply to use parametrized queries and don't try and remove any `'`. One example would be this:

```
dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("update Table1 set PhoneNo = ? where Table1.Company =? ", dbConnection);

dbCommand.Parameters.Add(phone);
dbCommand.Parameters.Add(company);
```

The OleDbCommand class allows you to specify parameters by name also, according to MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.aspx

So you could replace those `?` in my example, with actual parameter names like so:

```
dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("update Table1 set PhoneNo = @phone where Table1.Company =@company ", dbConnection);

dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@phone",phone);
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@company",company);
```

**Update (Comment from Steve)**

> You could use a name for the parameter, but it is ignored by OleDb. If
>   you change the order in which you add the parameter the query doesn't
>   work – Steve

Comment: You could use a name for the parameter, but it is ignored by OleDb. If you change the order in which you add the parameter the query doesn't work

Comment: @Steve didn't know that. Thanks for letting me know. Will add a comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to this

```
dbCommand = new OleDbCommand("update Table1 set PhoneNo =  @PhoneNo  where Table1.Company   = @company ", dbConnection);
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNo", phone );
dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@company", company );
```

Comment: @Steve Oups. I forgot parameters. I have fixed :) thx for mention.